# El header se monta sobre el main si lo pongo fixed

Tags: html, css

Si pongo el header fixed, lo que sigue se pone abajo y no se ve/lee, y si a esto le pongo margen, todo se mueve en conjunto, y sigue estando abajo. Lo que deseo es scrolear por la página y que el banner y menú se sigan viendo.

```css
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

header{
    width: 100%;
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0px;
    position: relative;
   
}
 
.container{
    height: 40px;
    background-color: rgba(110, 110, 110, 0.753);
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
   
}


.main{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(161, 140, 209, 0.5) 0%, rgba(251, 194, 235, 0.5) 100%), url(/img/dflag.jpg);  
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
</head>

    <body>
        <header class="container" id="containerheader">
            <div class="banner" id="banner">
                <img src="./img/bannerKup.jpg" alt="KupEntrenamientos">
            </div>
            <div class="container" id="containernav">
            
                <a href="#Ejercicios">Ejercicios</a>
                <a href="#Artículos">Artículos</a>
                <a href="#Contacto">Contacto</a>
                <a href="#Login">Login</a>
        
        </div>

        </header>
   
      <div class="main">
          <section class="container1" id="Ejercicios">
<h1> Ejercicios</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat illum totam optio, earum pariatur necessitatibus quia minus quam dolorem veritatis perspiciatis. Molestiae reprehenderit eos, obcaecati hic culpa recusandae in voluptatum.</p>

          </section>

          <section class="container2" id="Artículos">
            <h1>Articulos</h1>   
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat illum totam optio, earum pariatur necessitatibus quia minus quam dolorem veritatis perspiciatis. Molestiae reprehenderit eos, obcaecati hic culpa recusandae in voluptatum.</p>
        </section>

        <section class="container3" id="Contacto">
            <h1>Contacto</h1> 
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat illum totam optio, earum pariatur necessitatibus quia minus quam dolorem veritatis perspiciatis. Molestiae reprehenderit eos, obcaecati hic culpa recusandae in voluptatum.</p>
        </section>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución es poner el header arriba y como dices fixed.

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
```

Como ves le he añadido **top:0**
Y lo de poner los estilos en archivo aparte es fácil:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
```

Normalmente se pone en la sección head